# Can I automatically refactor an entire java project and rename uppercase method parameters to lowercase?

Tags: java, ide, refactoring, intellij-idea

I'm working in a java project where a big part of the code was written with a formatting style that I don't like (and is also non standard), namely all method parameters are in uppercase (and also all local variables).

On IntellJ I am able to use "Analyze -> Inspect Code" and actually find all occurrences of uppercase method parameters (over 1000).

To fix one occurrence I can do "refactor > rename parameter" and it works fine (let's assume there is no overlapping).

Is there a way to automagically doing this refactor (e.g: rename method parameter starting with uppercase to same name starting with lowercase)?

Comment: What OS? Sounds like a job for sed/awk

Comment: I don't think OS really matters here.  What I require is a "java structural" replace and sed/awk are not really ideal for that.

Comment: Given this relatively unusual requirement they might just be.

Comment: no, I disagree. parsing java with sed is like parsing html with regex. don't do it, get a tool that understands the language.

Comment: Actually batching of refactorings would be great, but i actually don't know a tool that can do this out of the box.

Comment: You can write your own eclipse plugin, that uses the refactoring api; but this won't be a joyful experience.

Comment: [http://staff.cs.utu.fi/kurssit/doos/JavaRenaming.pdf] is a paper describing how bad things can get when you are doing mass scale automated renaming. Most of the IDE-s fail at this, if your code has any of the patterns mentioned in the above paper ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use a Source Parser

I think what you need to do is use a source code parser like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) to do this.

For every java source file, parse it to a CompilationUnit, [create a Visitor](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser#Visiting_class_methods), probably using [ModifierVisitorAdapter](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/visitor/ModifierVisitorAdapter.java) as base class, and override (at least) [`visit(MethodDeclaration, arg)`](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/source/browse/trunk/JavaParser/src/japa/parser/ast/visitor/ModifierVisitorAdapter.java#651). Then write the changed CompilationUnit to a new File and do a diff afterwards.

I would advise against changing the original source file, but creating a shadow file tree may me a good idea (e.g. old file: `src/main/java/com/mycompany/MyClass.java`, new file `src/main/refactored/com/mycompany/MyClass.java`, that way you can diff the entire directories).

Comment: Definitely. It must be complicated to work, because you have changes on all levels. The only sensible alternative I can think of would be to script the IDE.

Comment: In the end this actually was the solution.  Was not so much code in the end, didn't change the formatting of the existing code, only the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise that you think about a few things before you do anything:

1. If this is a team effort, inform your team.
2. If this is for an employer, inform your boss.
3. If this is checked into a version control system, realize that you'll have diffs coming out the wazoo.
4. If it's not checked into a version control system, check it in.
5. Take a backup before you make any changes.
6. See if you have some tests to check before & after behavior hasn't changed.

This is a dangerous refactoring.  Be careful.

Comment: Also look for `Class.forName` - they mean "DON'T TOUCH!"

Comment: I disagree with the comment that this is a dangerous refactoring.  Renaming method parameters, especially, is about the safest refactoring you can do.  Agree you should inform your team, but no need to make a whole project out of just renaming stuff...

Comment: Dangerous because of the scale.  I would agree that renaming a variable is innocuous, but if the whole project is written incorrectly you have a greater probability of missing something and borking the whole thing.  There was no indication that the OP planned to inform anybody about this move.  An opportunity to educate and inform would have been lost.  But you're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any direct support for such refactoring out of the box in IDEs. As most IDEs would support name refactoring (which is regularly used). You may need to write some IDE plugin that could browse through source code (AST) and invoke rename refactoring behind the scene for such parameter names matching such format.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of such refactorings on a rather large scale of files, using TextPad or WildPad, and a bunch of reg-ex replace-all. Always worked for me!

I'm confident that if the code is first formatted using an IDE like Eclipse (if it is not properly formatted), and then a reg-ex involving the methods' signature (scope, return-type, name, bracket, arg list, bracket) can be devised, your job will be done in seconds with these tools. You might need more than one replace-all sets of reg-ex.

The only time-taking activity would be to come up with such a set of reg-ex.

Hope this helps!