# mass renaming of java variables

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a class with about 50 fields. They are named roughly like this:

```
config__write_better_code
```

I want them to look like this instead and not have to rename them all manually:

```
Config$WriteBetterCode
```

I'm using eclipse, but anything that can rename the code is welcome.

Comment: How can we tell you... You have a design problem.

Comment: 50 fields. Will take only a few minutes to do it by hand.

Comment: "$" is reserved: "The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."

Comment: Use the Refactor->Rename feature in eclipse for each variable.

Comment: Just use alt+shift+r 50 times. Shouldn't take too long. (that is the shortcut to rename variables in Eclipse, it will also modify wherever it is used).

Comment: I was thinking of using regexes, but they can't save the character and make it uppercase. I need some character that doesn't get used normally in variableNames and so I just took the dollar sign, my pc won't explode now will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AnyEdit Eclipse plugin might help you (in combination with the rename feature of eclipse):

http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/

> Convert Camel <-> Underscores
>
> Auto-convert variable names from/to "camel" notation, like  thisIsMyFieldName <-> this_is_my_field_name

Comment: Just checked, and 1) It only renames one line, not all variable usages 2) It only renames 1 variable, and only if selected

Answer (score 2):

click on the variable name.

1:press [alt] + [shift] + [R]

2:enter the new name.

3:press [enter] to confirm.

-->all instances of this variable will be renamed.

Comment: Thx, but I know how to refactor. I was thinking more of a regex based way, because all variables are named by the same pattern.