# Refactoring variable names in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

In a java project I'm creating a bunch of subclasses of an abstract class.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    protected String myFoo;
}

public class SubFoo extends Foo {
    public void fooMethod() {
        super.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0].set(this, "something");
    }
}
```

because of a nasty habit of renaming variable names all the time I refrain from referring to them by name, which gets tiresome.. Writing this question I'm realizing a better solution would be a setter method in `Foo`, but I really prefer not to, so my question stands:

Is there a way to refactor variable names in Eclipse such that all references to the old variable, in all classes, are updated?  `ALT+SHIFT+R` only changes in the same class :(

Comment: see this solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308352/renaming-a-lot-of-variables-in-many-java-classes-at-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALT+SHIFT+R` does rename all instances.